# swift for loop order of data is not right

Tags: swift, firebase, for-loop, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I want to fetch data from firebase and put them in an array. The first part of the function is always in the right order, i can see it when i print(DEBUG(files). But after for loop, the order of the documents messes and i always get random order. Shouldn't i always get the same order?

```
func getUnreadMessages(){

    guard let uid = AuthViewModel.shared.userSession?.uid else {return}
    Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(uid).collection("chats").order(by: "created", descending: true).getDocuments { (snapshot, _) in
        guard let files = snapshot?.documents.compactMap({ $0.documentID }) else {return}
        print("DEBUG: \(files)")
        
        for file in files{
            Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(uid).collection("chats").document(file).collection("messages").whereField("read", isEqualTo: false).getDocuments { (snapshot, _) in
                guard let documents = snapshot?.documents.compactMap({ $0.documentID }) else {return}
                print("DEBUG: \(documents)")
                self.count.append(documents.count)
                print("DEBUG: \(self.count)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are making asynchronous calls so there is no guarantee in which order you get the replies.

Comment: “Shouldn't i always get the same order?” No, and you should not write code that depends upon the order.

Comment: That code reads the same collection over and over. e.g. it reads `.collection("users").document(uid).collection("chats")` which means that collections documents are available in code. Then it's reading that same collection again within a tight loop; there's no reason to do that. Once a collection has been read, the documents within that collection (the snapshot) can be iterated over. It also seems the attempted task is to get a document count? If so, the function name shouldn't be `getUnreadMessages` because that's not what it's doing. Can you clarify the question and code?

Answer (score 0):

You get a different order of results because while you call the database in the correct order, there is no guarantee that the database will return your call in that same order, because some calls take longer than other calls. I think the simplest solution is to record the original order, attach it to the data in your second call (where you determine document count), and sort the collection (the array) by that original order.

The easiest way to attach this index value to the document count is a custom model:

```
struct MessageCount {
    let count: Int // this is the message count you're after
    let n: Int // this is the index of the original order
    
    init(count: Int, n: Int) {
        self.count = count
        self.n = n
    }
}
```

Then just use a dispatch group to coordinate the async tasks and in the completion of the dispatch group, sort the array by `index` and you will have an array of message counts in the intended order:

```
func getUnreadMessages() {
    guard let uid = AuthViewModel.shared.userSession?.uid else {
        return
    }
    let db = Firestore.firestore() // instantiate it once since it could be created hundreds or thousands of times in this function
    
    db.collection("users").document(uid).collection("chats").order(by: "created", descending: true).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        guard let snapshot = snapshot,
              !snapshot.isEmpty else {
            if let error = error {
                print(error) // you oddly omitted the error in your code, never do that
            }
            return
        }
        let dispatch = DispatchGroup() // set up the dispatch group outside the loop
        var messageCounts = [MessageCount]() // this temp array will carry the data with the index
        
        // to record the original order of the loop, just enumerate it and access `n` (the index)
        for (n, doc) in snapshot.documents.enumerated() {
            dispatch.enter() // enter dispatch on each iteration
            
            db.collection("users").document(uid).collection("chats").document(doc.documentID).collection("messages").whereField("read", isEqualTo: false).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
                if let snapshot = snapshot {
                    let c = snapshot.count // get the message count
                    let count = MessageCount(count: c, n: n) // add it to the model along with n which is captured by the parent closure
                    
                    messageCounts.append(count) // append to our temp array
                } else if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                }
                
                dispatch.leave() // leave dispatch no matter the outcome
            }
        }
        
        // this is the completion handler of the dispatch group
        dispatch.notify(queue: .main) {
            // sort the array by index and then map it to just get the message counts
            let counts = messageCounts.sorted(by: { $0.n < $1.n }).map({ $0.count })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The order of returned results are determined by an `order(by` clause. Otherwise the results may seem somewhat random.

In this case the first Firebase call specifies an order, so those documents will always be returned in the correct order.

```
collection("chats").order(by: "created"
```

But the next firebase call does not specify an order so, the returned documents may be somewhat inconsistently ordered.

```
.collection("messages").whereField
```

We need to have some way to guarantee that order.

Suppose the structure is this

```
chats (collection)
   user ids (documents)
      chats (collection)
         chat ids (documents)
            messages (collection)
               message ids (documents that you want ordered)
```

the message id's would need to have a field to order them by - call that `ordering`

Here's the code that prints the count of the number of messages in each chat id and then prints the messages in order

```
func getUnreadMessages() {
    let uid = "uid_0"
    self.db.collection("users_chats").document(uid).collection("chats").getDocuments(completion: { snapshot, error in
        if let err = error {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        guard let docs = snapshot?.documents else { return }

        for doc in docs {
            let ref = doc.reference.collection("messages")
            ref.order(by: "ordering").getDocuments(completion: { messagesSnapshot, error in
                if let err = error {
                    print(err.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }

                guard let messages = messagesSnapshot?.documents else { return }

                print("the chat document: \(doc.documentID) has \(messages.count) messages")
                for msg in messages {
                    let order = msg.get("ordering")
                    let msg = msg.get("read")
                    print("order: \(order!)", "is read: \(msg!)")
                }
            })
        }
    })
}
```

if there were three messages in chat 0, the output looks like this

```
the chat document: chat_0 has 3 messages
the chat document: chat_1 has 0 messages
the chat document: chat_2 has 0 messages
order: 0 isRead: 0
order: 1 isRead: 1
order: 2 isRead: 0
```